# How to remotely debug a shared library with an external executable using CLion?

Tags: c++, clion

I have built a shared library `logic.so`. This library is used by another executable program `executable.bin`, which I do not have the source codes. The path of this shared library will be passed as an argument to the executable program, like `executable.bin /path/logic.so`, and the library will be loaded during the runtime.

`logic.so` and `executable.bin` are both located on a ssh server. Is there any way that I can use CLion to debug my shared library?

I tried to add a CMake Application in Run/Debug Configurations and select `executable.bin`, but it seems that only local files can be selected.